# Prevent hyperref from underlining certain things

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, footmisc

Is there any way to prevent hyperref from underlining:

1) glossary entries linked with `\gls`

2) footnote marks of the `\footnote`

3) footnote marks set with `\footref` from the `footmisc` package?

MWE for testing (you will need to compile it twice).

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\hypersetup{
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0.5},%
}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name=foo, description=bar}

\begin{document}

This document uses the most advanced \gls{foo} technology.

There is also a footnote\footnote{\label{fn}This is the footnote}. 
It can be referenced multiple times.\footref{fn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about normal \ref commands and other internal document links. Should they loose the underlining too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer We definitely have some places where underlining is still needed; for example, \ref links linking to other chapters, and some links to a particular appendix. I suppose we could define some kind of "\underlinedRef" command which would underline those and search&replace manually, but that is not preferable.

Comment: Then it is not something that can be done at the hyperref level. This commands share the same internal command and so the same default settings. You will have to modify \gls and \footref etc to locally reset the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer mentioned: you have to modify `\gls` and all other commands that need modified links to locally reset the hyperlink style.

To do this you can use the `xpatch` package to add a `\hypersetup` command at the start of the commands to be modified, and another `\hypersetup` command at the end of these commands.

However, this does not always work, for example `\gls` is not a complete command that processes its arguments, but instead it calls the internal `glossaries` command `\@gls` to process the arguments. Simplified: `\gls` is rewritten to `\initialstuff\@gls`, which means that `\gls{abc}` is executed as `\initialstuff\@gls{abc}`. So if you append `\hypersetup` to `\gls` it instead becomes something like `\initialstuff\@gls\hypersetup{}`, which means that `\gls{abc}` will be executed as `\initialstuff\@gls\hypersetup{}{abc}`, which does not work. The obvious solution here is to patch `\@gls` instead. Similarly, to append something to `\footnote` you need to patch `\@footnotetext`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % for demonstration purposes
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\gls}{\hypersetup{hidelinks}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@gls}{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0.5}}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\footnote}{\hypersetup{hidelinks}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@footnotetext}{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0.5}}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\footref}{\hypersetup{hidelinks}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\footref}{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0.5}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\hypersetup{
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0.5},%
}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name=foo, description=bar}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}

This document (See \Cref{sec:first}) uses the most advanced \gls{foo} technology. See again \Cref{sec:first}.

There is also a footnote\footnote{\label{fn}This is the footnote}. 
It can be referenced multiple times.\footref{fn} See \Cref{sec:first} for the third time.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! (Heads-up for future readers: You probably also want to add `\xpretocmd{\glspl}{\hypersetup{hidelinks}}{}{}` as well.)